# How to split/group a list of dataframes by the length of each data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a list of 100 data frames, some have column length of 8, others 10, others 12. I want to be able to split these into groups based on their column length. I have tried dictionaries but couldn't get it to append properly in a loop.

Previously tried code:

```
col_count = [8, 10, 12]

d = dict.fromkeys(col_count, [])

for df in df_lst:
    for i in col_count:
        if i == len(df.columns):
            d[i] = df
```

but this just seems to replace the values in the dict each time. I have tried .append also, but that seems to append to all keys.

Comment: What is the code you tried ?

Comment: this is not splitting, it is grouping

Comment: @VaidøtasI. It's splitting a list is what I meant. Yes it's also grouping the dataframes. Regardless, can you help or are you just here for that comment?.....

Comment: @ygorg I have updated the post with more info :)

Comment: @still_coding I have an answer for you. If it answers your question, then +1 and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a `df` to `d[column_count]`. You should append it.

You initialized d with `d = dict.fromkeys(col_count, [])` so `d` is a dictionary of empty lists.

When you do `d[i] = df` you replace the empty list by a DataFrame, so `d` will be a dictionary of DataFrame. If you do `d[i].append(df)` you will have a dictionary of list of DataFrame. (which is what you want AFAIU)

Also i'm not sure that you need the `col_count` variable. You could just do `d[len(df.columns)].append(df)`.

Comment: Could you expand on how I would use lists?

Comment: @still_coding i updated my answer hope it's clearer. Do not hesistate to put `print` everywhere in your code to see what happens.

Comment: When I change d[I] = df to d[I].append(df), the dataframe appends to all of the key's in the dictionary and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should suffice for you. Think of how to dynamically solve your problems to make better use of Python.

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: for i in range(1, 5):
   ...:     exec(f"df{i} = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range({i}), columns=list('ABCD'))") #making my own testing list of dataframes with variable length
   ...:

In [4]: df1 #one row df
Out[4]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0

In [5]: df2 #two row df
Out[5]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0

In [6]: df3 #three row df
Out[6]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0

In [7]: L = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5] #i assume all your dataframes are put into something like a container, which is the problem

In [13]: my_3_length_shape_dfs = [] #you need to create some sort of containers for your lengths (you can do an additional exec in the following In

In [14]: for i in L:
    ...:     if i.shape[0] == 3: #add more of these if needed, you mentioned your lengths are known [8, 10, 12]
    ...:         my_3_length_shape_dfs.append(i) #adding the df to a specified container, thus grouping any dfs that are of row length/shape equal to 3
    ...:         print(i)
    ...:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```